# Create an instace of a global class

Tags: apex, class, global

I have a class like:

```
global class InfoCheckIMEIChangeVehicle {
        public boolean deviceSubstitutionNeeded;
        public OCTO_Integration_Request__c ir;
        public Account endUserAccount;
        public Contract endUserContract;
        public ServiceContract endUserServiceContract;
        public Asset oldDevice;
        public Asset newDevice;
        public String activationType;
        public String channel;
        public Monitored_Object__c newVehicle;
        public Plate_Association__c newPlateAssoc;
        public boolean isSingleStep;
        public boolean wasSuspended;
        public boolean retriveInfo;
        public String firmware;
        public String serialNumber;
}
```

this code give me an error:

```
InfoCheckIMEIChangeVehicle info=new InfoCheckIMEIChangeVehicle();
        info.deviceSubstitutionNeeded = false;
        info.ir = ir;
        info.endUserAccount = endUserAccount;
        info.endUserContract = endUserContract;
        info.endUserServiceContract = endUserServiceContract;
        info.channel = channel;
        info.oldDevice=olddevice;
        info.newDevice=newdevice;
        info.newVehicle = newVehicle;
        info.newPlateAssoc = plateAssoc;
        info.isSingleStep = true;
        info.retriveInfo = false;
        info.wasSuspended = false;
```

how can I instance a variable for this class?

Comment: and what error are you getting?

Comment: To construct from outside the managed package you would need a `global` constructor and to use the package namespace prefix. But within the same code base the default no-args constructor should work. Add more detail to your question...

Comment: Are all the right hand sides valid objects? Meaning are you actually instantiating or querying for "ir", "endUserAccount", etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is giving you an error because you're not assigning values to the instance variables. Instead, it appears as though you're trying to recreate the class. Your code should look closer to something like this:

```
InfoCheckIMEIChangeVehicle info=new InfoCheckIMEIChangeVehicle();
info.deviceSubstitutionNeeded = false;
info.ir = 'variableName for an OCTO_Integration_Request__c';
info.endUserAccount = 'variableName for an Account';
info.endUserContract = 'variableName for a Contract';
info.endUserServiceContract = 'variableName for a ServiceContract';
info.channel = 'some string value';
info.oldDevice= 'variableName for an Asset';
info.newDevice= 'variableName for an Asset';
info.newVehicle = 'variableName for a Monitored_Object__c';
info.newPlateAssoc = 'variableName for a Plate_Association__c';
info.isSingleStep = true;
info.retriveInfo = false;
info.wasSuspended = false;
```